# MikTeX (2.9 32-bit in Win7) became very slow after installing few fonts

Tags: miktex, performance

I've installed few fonts (otf fonts converted by using `autoinst`, because I need to use `dvips`), in my MikTeX setup, I've kept the font sets in `localtexmf` and incorporate `localtexmf` root to the MikTeX root directory.

[image]

Then, I've refresh the setup by using

[image]

Same thing done both `admin` and `user` rights and it works fine, but `LaTeX` running time is affected by hugely, just a 10 page text takes ~5 mins to compile, but previously it takes just few seconds only, anything I did by mistake or any suggestion, please....

Comment: What is T for a drive type?

Comment: It is just a sharing drive, in which I kept all the font sets....

Comment: try if it is the problem, by moving it for a test to C:

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've tried, but still no improvement...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I switched over to Windows10 with MikTeX 2.9 (64 bit)